# UITableViewCell with button inside in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView with cells, every cell have information of products, the name of the product and the Id of the product. Every cell has a button that drives you to another screen with more details of the product.
My problem is that when I selects a cell, I have obtain the name and id of the product that belongs to the selected cell thanks to didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but when I touch the button inside the cell I don't trigger didSelectRowAtIndexPath and I can't obtain the id of the product, because of this I can't go to the next screen and show the information related to the selected product.
What could I do?

Comment: You can add an IBAction from button to cell, and add a protocol which will be implemented by your view controller (which is also confirming `UITableViewDelegate`) this protocol can have a method which will be called with cell instance, on button tap you can trigger this method on delegate by passing self, and finally once you have cell, you get indexpath by using `indexPath(for:` and passing the cell instance you have received, once you have indexpath than your code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and this can be same, infact you can move it to a function and call them from both methods

Comment: we can better help you if you can edit the question and add `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` implementation , and probably the cell code as well

Answer (score 0):

The question I will ask you which will help solve this is:

Are you using `IBAction` to transition as the action trigger for the button?

If Yes, then the IBAction will sit under the `UITableViewCell` which should contain `IBOutlet` for the `UILabels` holding the value of name, id and product information.

For example:

```
class SampleCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var idLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var informationLabel: UILabel!


 @IBAction func action(button: UIButton) {
     // you can obtain your information once the button is triggered before navigating

     let id = self.idLabel.text
     let name = self.nameLabel.text
     let information = self.informationLabel.text
     
    // navigate to new screen using delegate protocols
 }
}
```

if you are not using IBOutlets and IBActions as follows, then I will suggest you use them, and create a custom TableViewCell for the product cell. It is the easiest way to access your cell information